# How to fix this?

Tags: eqnarray

I want to edit the problem of equal signs to be under each other.[image: undesirable output]

this code to me is perfect, so what would it be the problem.[image: the code of the undesirable output]

Comment: Don't use `eqnarray`. Use `align` from `amsmath`. Also, I think you can't wrap `eqnarray` in `equation`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!¨ Please provide code of your equation, not its image which we need to retype :-(. The best in form of MWE (Minimal working Example, a small complete document, which we can compile as it is). Something like thi: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a   & = b+c   \\
    & = 2+2
\end{align}
\end{document}`

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik that was absolutely effective. (approved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `split` math environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
\begin{split}
e_{0,1} & = \left(x,y\right)_{w(x)}, \\
        & = \left(x,y\right)_{w(x)}.
\end{split}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the modified code:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
e_{0,1} & = \left(x,y\right)_{w(x)}. \\
        & = \left(x,y\right)_{w(x)}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

This is its nice output.
[image]

@Phelype Oleinik thanks, sir.
Thanks, everyone.

Comment: `align` inside `equation` is not correct. Use `aligned` instead.

Comment: Also, for simple `x,y` you don't need `\left \right`. Use simply `(x,y)`.

Comment: Paste the code as code, not as image. Also, what @Sigur wrote: either only `align` either `aligned` within `equation`.

Comment: the best is to do what @Sigur said because no errors appeared, but the bracket's cases are optional.

Comment: @TCHassnaTaha, depends if you want a single number centered vertically or two numbers, one for each equation. If you want the last, simply use `align` only.

Comment: 'aligned' equal signs under each other but 'aligned*' all at the same line. in both cases, there is one number.

Comment: from where on the keyboard I can type the brackets of the code? I hope my question is clear.

Comment: `align` i guess i found it, thanks anyway.

Comment: but why `align` **sometimes** is right under  `equation` environment?